# Uncaught TypeError: slides[n].show is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

please help me with this error. Cant resolved this for the last couple hours. It seems like in function showSlide() don't work jQuery, but I cant understand why

slider.html

```
<section class="slider-container">
    <div class="slide-item">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1440x600" alt="" class="fx-img">
        <div class="min-text-block"></div>
        <div class="title-block"></div>
        <div class="description-block"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide-item">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1430x600" alt="" class="fx-img">
        <div class="min-text-block"></div>
        <div class="title-block"></div>
        <div class="description-block"></div>
    </div>
    <a class="slider-prev">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="slider-next">&#10095;</a>
</section>
```

style.scss

```
.slider-container {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  .slide-item {
    display: none;
  }
 ...
}
```

custom.js

```
$(function () {
    //SLIDESHOW

    var slideIndex = 1,
        nextSlide = $('.slider-next'),
        prevSlide = $('.slider-prev');

    showSlide(slideIndex);

    prevSlide.on('click', function () {
        slideIndex--;
        showSlide(slideIndex);
    });
    nextSlide.on('click', function () {
        slideIndex++;
        showSlide(slideIndex);
    });

    function showSlide(n) {
        var i,
            slides = $('.slide-item'),
            dots = $('.slider-dot');

        if ( n > slides.length) {
            slideIndex = 1
        }
        if (n < 1) {
            slideIndex = slides.length
        }
        $.each(slides, function () {
            $(this).hide();
        });
        console.log(slides[n-1]);
        slides[n-1].show();
    }

});
```

jQuery library adds before the custom script.

error text
https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3aLx.png

Comment: I think it would increase your chances if you narrow down the problem and reduce the amount of copy/paste code. Please also add the error text instead of forcing users to click a link to an external site.

Answer (score 0):

In the `showSlide` function,
you check if the value of `n` is within the correct bounds.
If it's too low or too high,
you set `slideIndex` to the beginning or to the end,
appropriately.
But the problem is that after these checks,
instead of using `slideIndex`,
you use `n`, which is unchanged.
And so if `n` is too high,
`slides[n]` will reference an `undefined` file,
and you get an error.

The fix is simple: use `slideIndex` after the checks, instead of `n`.
That's the variable whose value is verified within the correct ranges.

You also need to set `slideIndex` when `n` is within the bounds.
And the second `if` condition should be changed to an `else if`.

```
if (slides.length < n) {
    slideIndex = 1;
} else if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length;
} else {
    slideIndex = n;
}
$.each(slides, function () {
    $(this).hide();
});
console.log(slides[slideIndex - 1]);
slides[slideIndex - 1].show();
```